# How to convert string containing macro in wiki markup to xhtml format

Tags: confluence

During migration procedure from Confluence 3.5.13 to Confluence 5.0.3, I need in my MacroMigration class to convert a string containing some text and macro to xhtml format.

I've tried the following code:

```
    WikiStyleRenderer wikiStyleRenderer = (WikiStyleRenderer) ContainerManager.getComponent("wikiStyleRenderer");
    String result= wikiStyleRenderer.convertWikiToXHtml(new PageContext(context.getEntity()), body.getBody());
```

It works on simple text but as soon as it contains a reference to a macro (for example `{info:title=int Random(int range)}{info}`) the result is just an line feed (`'\n'`).

Answer (score 1):

I've succeeded to get it working using the com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.XhtmlContent interface. Here is how I did:

```
private XhtmlContent xhtmlContent;

public void setXhtmlContent(XhtmlContent xhtmlContent) {
    this.xhtmlContent = xhtmlContent;
}

public MacroDefinition migrate(MacroDefinition macroDefinition,
        ConversionContext context) {
    MacroBody body = macroDefinition.getBody();
    List<RuntimeException> migrationExceptions = new ArrayList<RuntimeException>();
    String resultContent;

    resultContent = xhtmlContent.convertWikiToStorage(body.getBody(),
            context, migrationExceptions);
```

The setter setXhtmlContent() is just there for Confluence to inject the right instance.

Comment: [Answered by the OP in a question edit. Moved to a wiki answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)